# Why am I getting this error in if elif else

Tags: if-statement, python-3.7

I am doing a school program again and when I enter <= on a range eg. >= 95 and <= 100 I get told the less than or = in <= is a syntax error.

[since I can't type copy and paste the code without errors here this is the code in full so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5tp6.png)

Comment: Please refer following link for get more idea about python if and elif https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_conditions.asp

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) You can use a comment to point out where the error happened. Also, `grade1 / grade2 / grade3` is almost certainly not what you want: the student that passes the first test with `100`, then proceeds to fail the other two tests with `1` will get an `A`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the variable in both paths of the expression: `if var >= 96 and var <= 100:`

Comment: Or `if 96 <= var <= 100:`